# Can't fix column width when have many column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't fixed column width when have a lot of column.
When user click + to see additional data, The column Product Type will not look good because of width.

I try to add something like `style="width:300px;"` but It isn't working
[image]
[image]

Please check the code follow link
https://jsfiddle.net/chanthida/vfLzt4mw/1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `min-width: 300px;` instead of `width: 300px;`.

Show the following snippet.

```js
$(".click-collapse").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('i').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.click-collapse').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow-x: auto;white-space: nowrap;">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th style="min-width:300px;">Product Type</th>
            <th>2019-11-14</th>
            <th>2019-11-15</th>
            <th>2019-11-16</th>
            <th>2019-11-17</th>
            <th>2019-11-18</th>
            <th>2019-11-19</th>
            <th>2019-11-20</th>
            <th>2019-11-21</th>
            <th>2019-11-22</th>
            <th>2019-11-23</th>
            <th>2019-11-24</th>
            <th>2019-11-25</th>
            <th>2019-11-26</th>
            <th>2019-11-27</th>
            <th>2019-11-28</th>
            <th>2019-11-29</th>
            <th>2019-11-30</th>
            <th>2019-12-01</th>
            <th>2019-12-02</th>
            <th>2019-12-03</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Superior </td>
            <td> RB - NRF </td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
             <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
           
        </tr>
        <tr class="click-collapse">
        <td> <a style="cursor: pointer;"> Click me <i>-</i> </a></td>
            <td colspan="21"></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
               test test test test test test test 
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              test 2
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="click-collapse"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this will works perfectly for you.

Thank you.

Comment: @banku, Attention please, with this css you can't set width:300px, You must need to use box-sizing: border-box; for set perfect with in your column. Thank you! :)

Comment: @jaydeep patel kindly you may attention please he used BS-4 in BS-4 there is a default css to *{box-sizing: border-box;}. means every element of body had this css property.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
width: 15%;
```

if text in column is too long, you can use functions `sub string`
OR you try delete `white-space: nowrap;` in style first div.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this design using `box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 300px;`
Let me know further clarification

Hope this will work for you. :)

```css
table td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto;white-space: nowrap;">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th style="width:300px;">Product Type</th>
            <th>2019-11-14</th>
            <th>2019-11-15</th>
            <th>2019-11-16</th>
            <th>2019-11-17</th>
            <th>2019-11-18</th>
            <th>2019-11-19</th>
            <th>2019-11-20</th>
            <th>2019-11-21</th>
            <th>2019-11-22</th>
            <th>2019-11-23</th>
            <th>2019-11-24</th>
            <th>2019-11-25</th>
            <th>2019-11-26</th>
            <th>2019-11-27</th>
            <th>2019-11-28</th>
            <th>2019-11-29</th>
            <th>2019-11-30</th>
            <th>2019-12-01</th>
            <th>2019-12-02</th>
            <th>2019-12-03</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Superior </td>
            <td> RB - NRF </td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
             <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
            <td>1650</td>
           
        </tr>
        <tr class="click-collapse">
        <td> <a style="cursor: pointer;"> Click me <i>-</i> </a></td>
            <td colspan="21"></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
               test test test test test test test 
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              test 2
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="click-collapse"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```